# Python 3 Filter from an unhashable Dictionary for LTO Tape Archive

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, filter

I'm quite new to Python, so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

I'm currently working on a filter for Tape Archives. What I'm getting out of the tape library is a long csv list with several columns like "Path, Media, MD5, etc."

I wrote a small filter script to read out the files written on tape only (all tapes start with K and are written in the Media column)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

def callback():
 filename = askopenfilename()
# print(filename)
  return filename


errmsg = 'Error!'
Button(text='File Open', command=callback).pack(fill=X)

inputfile = callback()

import csv

def tapefilter():
with open(inputfile, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    for row in reader:
        if 'K' in row['Media'] and 'DT' in row['Path']:
            x = row['Path']
            x = x.replace("/Backups","")
            x = x.replace("/Volumes/", "")
            x = x.split("/")
            yield x

def output():
for x in tapefilter():
    print(x[0], x[2])

output()
```

What I'm getting now is

```
K00130 20170504_DT12
K00130 20170505_DT13
K00130 20170508_DT14
K00130 20170508_DT14_part02
K00130 20170511_DT17
K00130 20170508_DT14_part03
K00130 20170508_DT14_part03
K00130 20170508_DT14_Masterfiles
K00130 20170508_DT14_part03
K00130 20170508_DT14_part03
K00130 20170508_DT14_part03
K00130 20170508_DT14_Masterfiles
K00130 20170508_DT14_part03
K00130 20170508_DT14_part03
K00130 20170508_DT14_part03
K00131 20170508_DT14_part03
K00131 20170508_DT14_part03
K00131 20170508_DT14_part03
```

What I need is a filter, which only outputs the the tape name and the rows which are different. So either the tape number changes or something in this particular part of the path (the whole path is much longer).

```
"/Volumes/K00131/Backups/Testproject/20170518_DT22/Alexa_ProRes/A032R72N",K00131,".cardmeta.xml"
```

All filter scripts I found so far always throw out the "non hashable" errors.

In the end, it should look like this:

```
K00130 20170504_DT12
K00130 20170505_DT13
K00130 20170508_DT14
K00130 20170508_DT14_part02
K00130 20170511_DT17
K00130 20170508_DT14_part03
K00130 20170508_DT14_Masterfiles
K00131 20170508_DT14_part03
```

I'm kinda stuck :/

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you step through the rows, you can just store the previous rows, and compare them to the new row: if there's a match then just skip to the next one without yielding a value:

```
def tapefilter():
    with open(inputfile, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        prev_values = [] # <- keep a list of previous (unique) values
        for row in reader:
            if 'K' in row['Media'] and 'DT' in row['Path']:
                x = row['Path']
                x = x.replace("/Backups", "")
                x = x.replace("/Volumes/", "")
                x = x.split("/")
                if (x[0], x[2]) in prev_values:
                    continue # <- don't yield if we've already seen this row
                else:
                    prev_values.append((x[0], x[2])) # <- update prev_values
                    yield x
```

Results:

```
K00130 20170504_DT12
K00130 20170505_DT13
K00130 20170508_DT14
K00130 20170508_DT14_part02
K00130 20170511_DT17
K00130 20170508_DT14_part03
K00130 20170508_DT14_Masterfiles
K00131 20170508_DT14_part03
```

Comment: Thank you! That is actually a really nice and easy solution :) unfortunately I still get duplicates in the line. I think it has something to do with the fact, that the actual 'Path' Value is longer than the value the script is printing
for example:
    K00130 20170508_DT14

actually is 
    K00130 20170508_DT14/ArriAlexa/etc...
but split via x.split("/")

Comment: I edited the code above, so it checks `(x[0],x[2])` instead of the full value of `x`... please see if that helps (I can't test without seeing more of your data)